# Writing this jquery code inline, bind function and callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var callBack = function(event, ui) {
    setModel.call(this, ui);
};

this.renderer.$el.on("slide", callBack.bind(this));
```

Hey I need help on how to write this without callback variable. How to define anonymous function directly in event handler without callBack variable, and bind it to this? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
this.renderer.$el.on("slide", function(event, ui) {
    setModel.call(this, ui);
});
```

Comment: where is bind? I need contests of upper objects, that's why I need to bind it. This suggestion is wrong.

Comment: @Vikast There is not need to bind `this`. Automatically in function `this` is accessible